jmeter auth token issue in /index.cfm/public:auth?fw1 application
I have /index.cfm/public:auth?fw1 web application, which I have to test using Jmeter. The application has secure protections as a username, password and auth token (xsrfTokenValue, xsrfTokenOrigin, xsrfTokenOrigin) and cookies (AWSALB,AWSALBCORS,CFID,CFTOKEN,TA_SID). Auth token and cookies is changing with every new session. I have done regular expression for token, beenshall for cookies, chage jmeter properti file as well, but still on index.cfm/public:auth/doLogin, i am getting 403 error, and there for I amn not able to login on the application, can anyone help me?

I don't know what "beenshall for cookies" means, normally you should add HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan and it will take care of cookies automatically.
With regards to the token - make sure that regular expression matched the token and you have its value in the JMeter Variable, you can do this using Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination.
Once you properly correlate all the dynamic parameters your login should be successful.
